# Setting the INSTALLDIR programatically in InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield

I am trying to set the change the INSTALLDIR programatically in InstallShield v8.02 (cannot do anything about the version).

My code crashes with an exception "Unknown error" on the third line of this code (C#)

```
String originalInstallDir = testProject.get_INSTALLDIR();
String installDir = originalInstallDir.Replace("Company", "Company Test");
testProject.set_INSTALLDIR(ref(installDir));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some info on what type of project this is? Basic MSI?  Also is that code InstallScript? Thanks

Comment: The code is c#, calling the ISWiAutomation COM componenent. None of the code is running inside InstallShield.

Comment: Do you still need this question? Given the age, perhaps it is time to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better migrate to latest version of Installshield and with the help of Installscript you can achieve it by using INSTALLDIR property.